# How do I get _all_ the NSURLRequest data?

Tags: ios, swift, macos, nsdata, nsurlrequest

I'm going to be using a different protocol, so probably implementing a NSURLProtocol handler.  Anyway, the server still basically wants a HTTP request.  Which I have already when I'm talking HTTP.

I suppose I can serialize it but the code must be out there somewhere...just not sure where.  Anyone know?

Eg: I want this....from a NSURLRequest

```
POST /some/control/endpoint HTTP/1.1
Header: Blah blah
Header2: Foo Bar

[Body data here]
```

Thanks

Comment: And this cannot be assembled from the properties?

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking how to construct the request, it is basically:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:...];
[request addValue:@"Blah blah" forHTTPHeaderField: @"Header"];
[request addValue:@"Foo Bar" forHTTPHeaderField: @"Header2"];
request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";
```

Then create an upload task and provide the body data.  Note that you'll also probably have to include Content-Length and Content-Type headers, too.

But if you're asking how to get the data in the format you show above *from* a request, you pretty much have to construct it yourself with string concatenation.  Remember that you need to send \r\n at the end of each header line to be spec-compliant.

Or if you need a fully compliant protocol implementation, it might be simpler to create yourself a local listen socket, point NSURLSession at it, capture the request, forward it, capture the response, and forward it back.